# Can't access public void method

Tags: java, android

I have this method in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
public void filter(String text) {
    mDataSet.clear();
    if(text.isEmpty()){
        mDataSet.addAll(mDataSet);
    } else{
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        for(AppInfo item: mDataSet){
            if(item.getAppName().toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                mDataSet.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and I'm trying to access it from my `Activity` by calling:

```
search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Here is where I'm trying to call the method
            mAdapter.filter(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But for some reason I can't access the method. Can someone please explain to me why that is?

Comment: What have you declared `mAdapter` as? A `RecyclerView.Adapter` or the name of your custom class?

Comment: @MichaelDodd as a `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Comment: Got it. I'll explain in an answer, but basically you need to declare `mAdapter` as whatever the name of your adapter class is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've declared `mAdapter` as a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, so you can only access the methods declared in `RecyclerView.Adapter`, not your custom class. As an example, let's say you have two classes:

```
public class Adapter {
    public void firstMethod() {}
}

public class ExtendedAdapter extends Adapter {
    public void secondMethod() {}
}
```

- If you declare `mAdapter` as an instance of `Adapter`, you'll only be able to call `firstMethod()` as the compiler is only aware of that method.
- However, if you declare `mAdapter` to be an instance of `ExtendedAdapter`, you'll be able to access `firstMethond()` by inheritance, as well as `secondMethod()` which only belongs to `ExtendedAdapter`.

So basically you need to declare `mAdapter` as an instance of the class that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`, whatever you may have called it.