# RecyclerView, adapter, click listener and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listener, android-recyclerview

I'm facing a issue while trying to implement AsyncTask (to fetch datas from USGS site). I've created an adapter to deal with datas and my recycler view.

Before implementing the AsyncTask I had an ArrayList of datas already populated and that worked fine. Now I want to make the request dynamic by fetching datas from internet. So I've implemented an AsyncTask but I think I'm not doing it right and, by the way, I've a blank page when I launch the app.

**EarthQuakeActivity.java**

```
public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<EarthQuake> mEarthQuakes = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String USGS_URL =
        "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=" +
                "earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=5&limit=10";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

    RecyclerView mEarthQuakeRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter earthQuakeAdapter;

    // Lookup the recyclerview in activity layout
    mEarthQuakeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_recycler_view);

    // Use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mEarthQuakeRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Set layout manager to position the items
    mEarthQuakeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    // Start the AsyncTask to fetch the earthquake data
    EarthQuakeAsyncTask earthQuakeAsyncTask = new EarthQuakeAsyncTask();
    earthQuakeAsyncTask.execute(USGS_URL);

    // Create adapter passing in the sample user data
    // Third argument is a new OnItemClickListener defining the onItemClick() method behavior
    earthQuakeAdapter = new EarthQuakeAdapter(
            mEarthQuakes,
            this,
            new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                    // Get the url string of the earthquake item at position position
                    String url = mEarthQuakes.get(position).getmURL();
                    // Define a new intent to browse the url of the specific item
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    // Start the intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
    mEarthQuakeRecyclerView.setAdapter(earthQuakeAdapter);
}

/**
 * AsyncTask to perform the network request on a background thread, and then
 * update the UI with the list of earthquakes in the response.
 * AsyncTask has three generic parameters: the input type, a type used for progress updates, and
 * an output type. Our task will take a String URL, and return an Earthquake List. We won't do
 * progress updates, so the second generic is just Void.

 * We'll only override two of the methods of AsyncTask: doInBackground() and onPostExecute().
 * The doInBackground() method runs on a background thread, so it can run long-running code
 * (like network activity), without interfering with the responsiveness of the app.
 * Then onPostExecute() is passed the result of doInBackground() method, but runs on the
 * UI thread, so it can use the produced data to update the UI.
 */
public class EarthQuakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<EarthQuake>> {
    /**
     * This method runs on a background thread and performs the network request.
     * We should not update the UI from a background thread, so we return a list of
     * EarthQuake(s) as the result.
     */
    @Override
    protected List<EarthQuake> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Don't perform the request if there are no URLs, or the first URL is null
        if (urls.length < 1 || urls[0] == null) return null;

        return QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(urls[0]);
    }

    /**
     * This method runs on the main UI thread after the background work has been
     * completed. This method receives as input, the return value from the doInBackground()
     * method.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<EarthQuake> list) {
        mEarthQuakes.clear();
        mEarthQuakes.addAll(list);
    }
}
```

**EarthQuakeAdapter.java**

```
public class EarthQuakeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EarthQuakeAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    /** Privates attributes */
// Define a member variable to store the context
private Context mContext;
// Define a member variable to store the earth quakes
private List<EarthQuake> mEarthQuakes;
// Define a member variable to set up the listener
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

/** Public constructors */
// Default constructor with no parameters
public EarthQuakeAdapter() {}

// Default constructor with parameters (we pass in the earthQuakes array into the constructor)
public EarthQuakeAdapter(List<EarthQuake> earthQuakes,
                         Context context,
                         OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mEarthQuakes = earthQuakes;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mListener = listener;
}

/** Inner class */
// Provide a direct reference to each of the view within a data item
// Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // Your holder should contain a member variable for any view that will be set as you
    // render a row
    private TextView magnitudeTextView;
    private TextView distanceOfLocationTextView;
    private TextView locationTextView;
    private TextView dateTextView;
    private TextView timeTextView;

    // We also create a constructor (by design) that accepts the entire item row
    // and does the view lookups to find each subview
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
        // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance
        super(itemView);
        magnitudeTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude_text_view);
        distanceOfLocationTextView =
                (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.distanceOfLocation_text_view);
        locationTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_text_view);
        dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text_view);
        timeTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text_view);
    }
}

/** Methods */
// Usually involves inflating a layout from XML and returning the holder
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    // Inflate the custom layout
    View earthQuakeView =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_earthquake, parent, false);
    // Create a new view holder
    final ViewHolder earthQuakeViewHolder = new ViewHolder(earthQuakeView);
    // Attach a listener on the earthQuakeView view
    earthQuakeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onItemClick(v, earthQuakeViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    // Return a new holder instance
    return earthQuakeViewHolder;
}

// Involve populating data into the item through holder
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Get the data model based on position
    EarthQuake currentEarthQuake = mEarthQuakes.get(position);

    // Call to getFormattedMagnitude to get a properly formatted magnitude string value
    String magnitudeOutput = getFormattedMagnitude(currentEarthQuake.getmMagnitude());

    // Set the proper background color on the magnitude circle.
    // Fetch the background from the TextView, which is a GradientDrawable.
    GradientDrawable magnitudeCircle =
            (GradientDrawable) holder.magnitudeTextView.getBackground();

    // Get the appropriate background color based on the current earthquake magnitude
    int magnitudeColor = getMagnitudeColor(currentEarthQuake.getmMagnitude());

    // Set the color on the magnitude circle
    magnitudeCircle.setColor(magnitudeColor);

    // Array that will contain the splitted location
    String[] distanceOfLocation = getFormattedLocation(currentEarthQuake.getmLocation());

    // Create a an object based on the item date and calls to functions to format the output
    // ex formatDate : "jan 28, 2016"
    // ex formatTime : "10:40"
    Date dateObject = new Date(currentEarthQuake.getmDate());
    String dateToDisplay = formatDate(dateObject);
    String timeToDisplay = formatTime(dateObject);

    // Set item views based on the view and data model
    holder.magnitudeTextView.setText(magnitudeOutput);
    holder.distanceOfLocationTextView.setText(distanceOfLocation[0]);
    holder.locationTextView.setText(distanceOfLocation[1]);
    holder.dateTextView.setText(dateToDisplay);
    holder.timeTextView.setText(timeToDisplay);
}...
```

Any idea of how to implement this would be very helpful.
If needed I can upload the full code on GitHub.

PS : I'm using an interface to specify the behavior of the standard onClick method from View.OnClickListener

**OnItemClickListener**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
void onItemClick(View v, int position);
}
```

Comment: Well, given that fetching datas is running in background, I guess I'm setting the adapter with an empty mEarthQuakes list and that's why I've a blank page. 

I've tried to set the adapter in the onPostExecute but I think this is not good practice...

Comment: consider to use a library to access remote data, like Volley, Retrofit or Spring Rest Template. It should simplify a lot remote data access

Comment: I prefer not to use external libraries while I'm currently learning but thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final List<EarthQuake> list) {
    mEarthQuakes.clear();
    mEarthQuakes.addAll(list);
}
```

into this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final List<EarthQuake> list) {
    mEarthQuakes.clear();
    mEarthQuakes.addAll(list);
    EarthQuakeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! Do you think I'm ok in terms of design here?

Comment: Well, if this is the only occasion, where you add a bunch of items to your List, you can leave it like that. But if there are more occations and you want to make sure, that the adapter gets notified everytime, then you should encapsulate it in a method, like beep said

Answer (score 0):

I'd add two functions to your adapter:

```
public void clear() {
    mEarthQuakes.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    // you can also call the other notify methods instead to provide animations
}

public void addAll(List<EarthQuake> newList) {
    mEarthQuakes.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    // you can also call the other notify methods instead to provide animations
}
```

Then inside your `onPostExecute()` call these functions:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final List<EarthQuake> list) {
    earthQuakeAdapter.clear();
    earthQuakeAdapter.addAll(list);
}
```

Comment: I've implemented Locdoc01's solution but yeah this is the same spirit here. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: No problem ;) I just won't modify data on the outside of the adapter. In my opinion the adapter should have it's own list and functions which modify that data. Benefit is that you always know where the data is modified and you can notify your adapter inside these modify functions so you don't have to call notify functions on the outside.

Comment: Actually I'm facing an problem with the implementation of both methods. I declared those methodes after the onBindViewHolder but I can't call them in the postExecute method which is weird cause they are declared public... (cannot resolve symbol clear and addAll)

Comment: Ok I figured out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410827/cant-access-public-void-method/49411050?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

I had to declare earthQuakeAdapter as a EarthQuakeAdapter not as a RecyclerView.Adapter. I don't know why I did that...